# General Help on Visual Studio using Common Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know this sounds very basic but I just started with visual studio and I am looking for instructions on the basic control functions.  In general, what the different options do.  I am just trying to get familiar with some of the functions and I am not completely understanding how to manipulate the data.  For example, how to trigger information in a textbox after hitting the return button instead of any input change in the window.  I know this sounds simple but its very frustrating getting started with the basics.  I am looking for a good book or online support forum that gets me over some of the simple hurdles.  Also, is there a clock function that I can use as a count down in a program that someone has done.

Thanks

Killing Myself

Answer (score 1):

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/

excellent tutorial videos, a very good place to start

Answer (score 0):

There are some video tutorials about programming in Visual Studio on the Internet. If you like books - take for a start something like lessons in VS.

To handle return button in textbox just handle KeyPressed event and in parameter e you have all necessary information.

To do something like clock you can use Timer component. It fires an event based on the timer interval period.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have some experience with similar programming - you could pick up a cookbook for the respective language you're trying to learn.
A cookbook has to the point answers which will get you up and running in no time.

I did the same thing when I wanted to pick up C#.Net after having done VB 6 previously.

However, if you want to spend some more time picking up things and getting to the crux of it all, I'd recommend a dummies book.

And yes, there is a clock control which you can drag and drop and program for the _tick event once you have enabled it and set its interval.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of great open-source (free) resources and tutorials on [DreamInCode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showforum84.htm)

I've solved several problems there and learned a few new techniques. What I like about it is that the tutorials walk you through step-by-step, and you get the source too.

[Timer help on DreamInCode.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=74593&hl=timer)